# Why can we cover a surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$ with *countably* many open orientable connected subsets?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

> Why can we cover a surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$ with *countably* many open orientable connected subsets?

This is a claim in my Differential Geometry book (Montiel and Ros, *Curves and Surfaces*, 2nd edition). To argue the authors invoke Lemma 3.2 below:

> Lemma 3.2: Let $S$ be a surface and let $X: U \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$ be a parametrization of $S$. Then there is a unit normal field defined on the open set $V = X(U)$.

Now, as I understand, Lemma 3.2 gives us a cover of $S$ with orientable connected subsets. Why can there be only countably many? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: Every subset of $R^n$ is [Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space).

Comment: That is, we take the union of all the $U$ sets, and we can find a countable family of subsets $U'$ for which the property of Lemma 3.2 is still valid, is that it?

Comment: Yes, a countable subfamily which still forms a cover of $S$.

Comment: Got this. Many thanks

Comment: This question got a downvote, I would like to know what I did wrong, if somebody could tell.

Comment: Do not know: I did not vote on your question either way.